# Riddle with functions

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

The following is a riddle, that is not so easy as it seems.
Using the numbers 1, 3, 4, 6 only once, you must use any of the functions (addition, multiplication, division, subtraction) in order to form the number 24.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work to get 24:

> $6/(1-3/4)$

Comment: That's correct. Good work!